# Trying to combine two columns using JSON on Sharepoint site

Tags: json, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am new to using JSON, I have been trying to develop JSON code to combine the results from two columns to set the color in a third column, I have been trying for two weeks now with no luck. This code is in a column called Mock, I am trying to read a column called Process which currently has the word Mock in it. I have a second column called Status which has the word Complete in it. Currently the cell I am interested in has the date 2/2/2022 in it. I cannot see any date in the cell.

```
{
 "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column- 
  formatting.schema.json",
 "elmType": "div",
 "txtContent": "@currentField",
 "style": {
 "background-color": "=if(Number(@currentField)==0,if($Process == 'Mock' && if($Status == 
 'Complete', '#0000FF','white'))"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please use the below JSON formatting:**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if(Number(@currentField) == 0,'',if(([$Process] == 'Mock' && [$Status] == 'Complete'),'#0000FF','#FFFFFF'))"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know what I am doing wrong but I added your code and it is not changing the color to Blue.  Maybe, I am putting the code in the wrong spot.

Comment: I am going to settings >> List settings >> Clicking on Column to add code to >>Then pasting the code into the column formatting box and saving

Comment: OK, I found out that one of my columns is not named the same as what is in the column Name. Once I changed it to that new name it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that your problem has been solved. If the answer is helpful to you, you can accept it as answer. The behavior will help others who meet the similar issue in the future quickly find the correct answer.